# Suggest a good Javascript library for draw charts and tables on one surface

Tags: javascript, charts

I need a suggest for a good Javascript library what can draw charts and tables on one surface something like this schematic chart:

[image].

On the left and right sides of charts I need to render table with several columns. Between left and right sides I need to draw charts. Nodes of charts must be allowed to select and navigate from keyboard: left-right between to nodes of one graphs and up-down between two graphs. Style of one chart between two nodes must be allowed to customize style.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/), I think this might be something that could prove useful.